# print both key and value with MDC

Tags: log4j

using MDC I wanted print both key and value.

With

```
MDC.put("key", value);
```

and the log4j pattern :

```
<pattern>%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level - %mdc{KEY} </pattern>
```

I have this result :

```
2019/04/11 16:25:52.983 WARN - **value**
```

but I expected

```
2019/04/11 16:25:52.983 WARN - **key=value**
```

my first idea was to append the key in the value but it's not very clean

```
MDC.put("key", "key " + value);
```

does anyone have a solution?

Thx

edit:

adding the key statically in the pattern is not a good solution

```
<pattern>%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level - key=%mdc{KEY} </pattern>
```

sometimes the value doesn't exist and it will print 'key='

Comment: I think your current approach might be as good as you can get.  But, why do you need to know the name of the key in the first place?  Given that each log entry is based off a template, you should know the corresponding given the position and content.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The key can be useful for doing research with kibana .. for example if I have to filter according to the key

Comment: Maybe, but why can't you just write a regex pattern instead?

Comment: it seems to be a good solution, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pattern this way:

```
<pattern>%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level - %mdc{KEY} </pattern>
```

then you are doing mdc.get(key) which is going to return just the value of this key.

Instead, if you want to get both the keys and values you can just update the pattern to

```
<pattern>%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level - %mdc </pattern>
```

and it'd print the entire content of the mdc as a key value pair.

Note: I am assuming that you use some mapper like Gson or Jackson to print the mdc as a json string for better key-value search in Kibana or Splunk.
If used correctly it'd be able to write the correct string on the console.